# What is the inverse of $f(x) = a⋅e^{bx} + cx + d$

Tags: exponential-function, inverse

Does an inverse function for

$f(x) = a⋅e^{bx} + cx + d$

exist where a, b, c, d are constants?  If so, what is it?

I've tried lots of methods, but they've all failed.

**What I ended up doing to approximate an inverse:**

For very small (very negative) values of y, I ended up using the following function:

$x = \frac{ln(\frac{y-cx-d}{a})}{b}$

to assist in a recursive approximation by which, after seeding x with a guess, I feed the function back on itself a few times.  For greater values of y, I used a similar method/function inspired by binary search algorithms. My implementations converged quickly for my purposes.

Thanks everyone who commented.

Comment: There isn't a solution in general. Some might reference the W Lambert function but I am not a fan of that argument. It's almost like saying "the solution is the solution!" The W Lambert function is constructed to be a solution to a related problem so it's circular to me.

Comment: @CameronWilliams But distinguish between the two cases (1) There is no inverse because the function is not $1-1$ and (2) There is an inverse, but not one with a closed form.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh doh. I meant to say "no solution in elementary functions." Slipped my mind. You're completely right.

Comment: @CameronWilliams The one nice thing about special functions like the Lambert W function is that they reduce a large family of problems to a smaller family of problems. This makes robust numerical implementation a lot easier. Solving an equation like that in the OP with Newton's method, the convergence properties may depend very strongly on the parameters.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: the benefit of "standardizing" the problem to the Lambert function is that the latter is a well-studied function. As soon as you reduce a problem to it, you immediately "inherit" all the knowledge about it. For instance, we know that it has no closed form.

Comment: I agree with Ian and Yves Daoust. So, it’s not surprising that I dislike the comment of Cameron Williams : << It's almost like saying "the solution is the solution!" The W Lambert function is constructed to be a solution to a related problem so it's circular to me. >>  Saying this is the same as saying  << The $\arcsin(x)$  function is constructed to be a solution to the problem of solving for $\alpha$ the equation $\sin(\alpha)=x$  so it's circular to me : It's almost like saying "the solution is the solution!".

Comment: In fact, there is no difference of concept between $\arcsin(x)$ and W($x$), except that  one is more common that the other. They are several examples of this kind in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$y = a⋅e^{bx} + cx + d$$ and make a change of variable $e^{bx}=z$. This then leads to $$y=a.z+\frac cb .\log(z)+d$$Any equation which can write $A+B x+C\log(Dx+E)=0$ has solution(s) in terms of Lambert function. For the particular case in the post, we should then obtain $$z=\frac{c }{a b}W(t)$$ where $$t=\frac{a b }{c}e^{\frac{b (y-d)}{c}}$$ and, back to $x$ (taking into account the fact that $t=W(t).e^{W(t)}$), $$x= \frac{y-d}{c}-\frac{1}{b}W(t)$$ The advantage of this is that there are very good approximations of Lambert function.

For illustration purposes, let us use $a=1,b=2,c=3,d=10^6$ and let us try to solve the equation for $y=2.10^6$. So, replacing, we have $$x=\frac{1000000}{3}-\frac{1}{2} W\left(\frac{2 e^{2000000/3}}{3}\right)$$ Now, let us use for the approximation $$W(t)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(t)$,$L_2=\log(L_1)$. This then leads to $x=6.907744917$ which is the exact solution for ten significant figures.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible for a function to have an inverse but with no closed formula for the inverse.

In this case, $f(x)$ is $1-1$ if and only if $f'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$ in the (interior of the) domain, which means if $abe^{bx}\neq -b$ has no solution, so if $\frac{-d}{ab}$ is negative.

However, combinations of $x$ and $e^x$ generally make it impossible to find a *formula* for the inverse function.

We can easily find a way to compute the inverse when $f$ is increasing or decreasing - just apply a binary-search algorithm to get a sequence of approximations to the inverse.